# Выборка с условием по колонке с датой и временем

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Не работает запрос:

```
select * 
from   table t
WHERE  FILL_DATE Between ('01.01.17 01:01:01,000000000', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:Mi:SS,FF')
                     and ('01.05.17 01:01:01,000000000', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:Mi:SS,FF')
```

Ошибка:

> ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis

Comment: А это какой именно plsql оракловый или postrgess. Вообще даты в таком формате не задаются ни там ни там

Comment: ага, значит все таки oracle. Это надо указывать в тегах вопроса. А строки в даты в оракле, раз вы уж готовы указать формат конвертируются функцией `TO_DATE('01.01.17 01:01:01,000000000', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:Mi:SS,FF')`

Comment: @Mike ответы в ответы

Comment: В общем тут надо или закрывать или плюсовать, а то дух "дух" испустит постоянно тему поднимать. Думаю последнее.

Answer (score 2):

В Oracle даты конвертируются функциями [TO_TIMESTAMP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm) и [TO_DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm).
Судя по Вашему формату у вас колонка типа `timestamp`. Запрос будет таким:

```
select * 
from   table t
WHERE  FILL_DATE Between TO_TIMESTAMP('01.01.17 01:01:01,000000000', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:Mi:SS,FF')
                     and TO_TIMESTAMP('01.05.17 01:01:01,000000000', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:Mi:SS,FF')
```

Answer (score 2):

Значения колонки с типом данных `TIMESTAMP` надо сравнивать с соответствующим ему литералом.

[Литерал отпечатка времени](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1) влючает дату, время и опционально, доли секунды вплоть до 9-и цифр после точки. Формат литерала фиксированный, изменить или указать его нельзя.

```sql
with t (created) as (
    select timestamp'2020-03-11 12:30:00' from dual
)
select * from t 
where created between timestamp'2020-03-10 00:00:00.000' 
                  and timestamp'2020-03-11 23:59:59.999999999';

CREATED                      
-----------------------------
2020-03-11 12:30:00,000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем усложнять? Сделай вот так:

```
select * 
from   table t
WHERE  FILL_DATE Between to_date('01.01.17', 'DD.MM.YY')
                     and to_date('01.05.17', 'DD.MM.YY');
```

А ошибка: **ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis** означает, что где-то не указана правая закрывающая скобка.. в этом коде не видно левой скобки, код не весь..

Comment: Ошибка ORA-00907 может означать любую синтаксическую ошибку после открывающей скобки. В данном случае на первой запятой

Comment: В моём куске кода всё правильно для Oracle. Я в нём работаю и так делаю выборку когда надо.. а у него где такая ситуация, что Вы пишите " на первой запятой"?

Comment: В вашем правильно, я про запрос автора. Что означает запятая в скобках, которые не относятся к вызову функции?

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста - _Зачем усложнять?_, что усложнять и какой критерий оценки сложности?

Comment: Имею ввиду, что выборка значений между (с '01.01.17 01:01:01,000000000' по '01.05.17 01:01:01,000000000') и (с '01.01.17' по '01.05.17') не будет отличаться, а код короче и проще. Если надо часы, минуты и секунды, то можно указать.

Comment: Выборка будет отличаться, например, строки со значением  '01.05.17 01:00:00' в вашем случае не будут выбраны.

Comment: Это да, но я дописал, что если надо, то часы/минуты можно добавить. Мой совет заключается в использовании to_date